# When is an event.target.value not a string?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling

I came accross `value = String(event.target.value || "")` when a textinputs keyup/keydown event is fired.

But i'm not sure when the `event.target.value` is not a string? Is this possible? When is something else passed off as an `event.target.value`?

Comment: It's either undefined or a string, and undefined evaluates as false, invocing the OR, so string conversion should'nt be neccessary but is probably added as some sort of insurance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the `event.target` element is not an input type element, it will not have a `value` property. For example, if I click a `div` then `event.target` is a div which does not have `value`.

Wrapping `event.target.value || ''` in `String()` is not necessary as it will always be either value (which is always a string or `undefined`) or the empty string in the case that value is `undefined`.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hBCF/) for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to break down what's happening here in that statement.
The key part is that `event.target.value || ""` evaluates first, before String() does.

Meaning, it is checking to see if `event.target.value` is null or undefined. If it IS null or undefined, it will use the blank string `""` as the default value. The outcome of this statement is then passed to String().