# React - Material-UI radio button group won't fill button on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, material-ui, radio-group

I'm building an app in **React** using **Material-UI** components. In one window there are four true/false choices represented by radio buttons. On render the window renders as expected, but clicking on a non-default value only causes the default radio button to lose its fill, and does not fill the clicked-on choice.

Example: if User can mint defaults to `false`, then `false` will be filled on render, but clicking `true` for that option won't fill `true` (though `false` will become 'unfilled').

The actual state does change, though. So this seems to only be a render problem, not an underlying problem with the state.

Here's the code (I'll try to take out the unnecessary parts):

```
const UpdateDefaultRole = props => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [canMint, setCanMint] = React.useState(false);
  const [canBurn, setCanBurn] = React.useState(false);
  const [payFee, setPayFee] = React.useState(true);
  const [paySplit, setPaySplit] = React.useState(true);

  const handleMintChange = e => setCanMint(e.target.value);
  const handleBurnChange = e => setCanBurn(e.target.value)
  const handleFeeChange = e => setPayFee(e.target.value)
  const handleSplitChange = e => setPaySplit(e.target.value)

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Update Default Role
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Update Default Role</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Please enter the new permissions for the default role.<br/> WARNING: Be careful! 
            Improper use of this function is dangerous!
          </DialogContentText>
          <FormControl component="fieldset" style={{padding: "20px", margin: "10px"}}>
            <FormLabel component="legend">User Can Mint Tokens:</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup aria-label="mint" name="can-mint" value={canMint} onChange={handleMintChange}>
              <FormControlLabel value={true} control={<Radio />} label="True" />
              <FormControlLabel value={false} control={<Radio />} label="False" />
            </RadioGroup>
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl component="fieldset" style={{padding: "20px", margin: "10px"}}>
            <FormLabel component="legend">User Can Burn Tokens:</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup aria-label="burn" name="can-burn" value={canBurn} onChange={handleBurnChange}>
              <FormControlLabel value={true} control={<Radio />} label="True" />
              <FormControlLabel value={false} control={<Radio />} label="False" />
            </RadioGroup>
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl component="fieldset" style={{padding: "20px", margin: "10px"}}>
            <FormLabel component="legend">User Must Pay Fee:</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup aria-label="fee" name="pay-fee" value={payFee} onChange={handleFeeChange}>
              <FormControlLabel value={true} control={<Radio />} label="True" />
              <FormControlLabel value={false} control={<Radio />} label="False" />
            </RadioGroup>
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl component="fieldset" style={{padding: "20px", margin: "10px"}}>
            <FormLabel component="legend">User Must Pay Split:</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup aria-label="split" name="pay-split" value={paySplit} onChange={handleSplitChange}>
              <FormControlLabel value={true} control={<Radio />} label="True" />
              <FormControlLabel value={false} control={<Radio />} label="False" />
            </RadioGroup>
          </FormControl>
          
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={submitUpdateDefaultRole} color="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried to follow the code on [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/components/radio-buttons/#radiogroup)'s site as loyally as possible, but I'm obviously messing up somewhere.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's a `string` and not a `boolean` and that is causing the issue. Try as:

```
const handleMintChange = e => setCanMint(e.target.value === 'true');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't really understand why it's a string, but this solved everything, after hours of trying to figure out the issue, with a n easy-to-follow fix. Thanks!

Comment: @TheRenaissance Anytime! I found further explanation in this question here for you: [When is an event.target.value not a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736026/when-is-an-event-target-value-not-a-string)

Comment: I hadn't realized everything gets turned into a string when it gets passed as an event value, but looking back, I probably should've suspected it. Thanks for the link!