# generic function component encounter error "'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'P'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I wrote 2 function components with generic type named GenericSelect and GenericSelect2. ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/generic-component-2-7shwrf?file=/src/GeniricSelect2.tsx))

Both of them have onSelect props.

The type of one is `(value: unknown) => void`, and the other one is `(value: T) => void`.

Everything is right with GenericSelect, but not with GenericSelect2.

I got a error message "type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'P'" when I tried to pass e.target.value to onSelect.

Why I got this error? And how to fix it, if I still want to keep type be `(value: T) => void`?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you should use overloads: https://tsplay.dev/wj8LYm

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `e.target.value` is always considered to be a `string`. (Even if the code has been written to contain a different value, as React so often does)
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736108/15291770) also points this out, I'm sure I've read other places where it's in the HTML specification, and I'll update my answer if I find them...

Because of this frustration, I prefer the use of something like the [React Select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) library for `select` inputs.

But going your own way, I would suggest you make use of the `as` keyword (see [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)).
It's something that you should use sparingly, and reserve for times *when you know better than the compiler.*

```js
interface GeniricSelectProps<T> {
  options: { text: string; value: T }[];
  onSelect: (value: T) => void;
}

const GeniricSelect2 = <T extends string | number>({
  options,
  onSelect
}: GeniricSelectProps<T>) => {
  return (
    <select
      name=""
      id=""
      style={{ padding: 8 }}
      onChange={e => onSelect(e.target.value as T)}
    >
      {options?.map(({ text, value }) => (
        <option value={value} key={value}>
          {text}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};

export default GeniricSelect2;
```

Note: I also removed the type allocation for `e` in the `onChange`, I did this because the type is already prescribed by the `onChange` prop type.