How to get the object of the currently selected option in a dropdown list when using Vue.js 3?
How to get the object of the currently selected option in a dropdown list when using Vue.js 3?
I think it might be best explained with an example:

<li v-for="todo in filteredTodos" :key="todo.id">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="todo.done">
  <span :class="{ done: todo.done }">{{ todo.text }}</span>
  <button @click="removeTodo(todo)">X</button>
</li>

Source: https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-8

From what I can see, the entire TODO object is passed to the removeTodo function (entire meaning the attributes of the currently selected li item).
I'm wondering if the same can be done using @change (for a dropdown list).
I've searched around (using event.target.value and the defineModel macro), and the best I can do is pass the currently selected value (not the entire TODO object) to the onChange function.

Assign IDs to your elements. Each <option> inside the <select> receives the ID as its value. This way, you will be able to extract it using event.target.value on the @change event. With the ID, you can perfectly find the object, which you can then modify/use.


const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const options = ref([
      { id: 1, name: "First" },
      { id: 2, name: "Second" },
    ])

    const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
      const selectedId = parseInt(event.target.value) // event.target.value will be string, but need number
      
      // and actually, it only took adding one extra line to reference the original object
      const selectedOption = options.value.find(option => option.id == selectedId);
      
      console.log(selectedOption)
    }
    
    return { options, handleSelectChange }
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select @change="handleSelectChange">
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" :value="option.id">{{ option.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>



Why can't the value be an option object?
The solution is that JavaScript cannot extract objects and arrays from the DOM, and even the numbers will be returned as strings. Since we get the object as a string, it cannot be interpreted. Other workaround solutions could be applied, but at the end of the day, the best approach will always be passing an identifier, based on which the original object can be precisely retrieved and manipulated.


// THIS IS A BAD EXAMPLE FOR QUICK REVIEW OF THE ANSWER TO THE QUESTION

const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const options = ref([
      { id: 1, name: "First" },
      { id: 2, name: "Second" },
    ])

    const handleSelectChange = (event) => {      
      // this way, we would just bypass the object lookup, but we will see that it doesn't work
      const selectedOption = event.target.value
      
      console.log(selectedOption)
    }
    
    return { options, handleSelectChange }
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
THIS IS A BAD EXAMPLE FOR QUICK REVIEW OF THE ANSWER TO THE QUESTION

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select @change="handleSelectChange">
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" :value="option">{{ option.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>




Why not just pass 'option' instead of only the id?

The value of event.target.value will always return as a string, so we are unable to handle objects directly. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736108/15167500)
I have implemented a code snippet in my response. Change the value of :value to option, and in the function, log the value of event.target.value, and you will immediately see the answer to your question, which is entirely valid and understandable.
